# Separar elementos de uma array para consulta com sequelize

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, sequelize-js

Esse id_mensagem eu envio por parametro por minha requisiçao, um console.log nisso me retorna o valor da imagem.

```
const id_mensagem = [...new Set(response.data.map(mensagens => mensagens.id_mensagem))]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no meu back eu recebo essa info dessa forma:

```
const {id_mensagem}  = req.params
```

um console.log me retorna `423,421,422`.

Porém preciso passar esse valor entre colchetes para uma consulta no banco de dados, código da consulta:

```
const mensagens = await Mensagens.findAll({
    where:{                    
        id_mensagem:{
            [Op.in]:[id_mensagem]
        }                                      
    },
    order: [['created_at','DESC']],
    
})
```

e ai vem o problema, estou usando sequelize nesse caso e quando ele faz a query e ele busca somente os primeiros números antes da virgula, um console.log([id_mensagem]) me retorna dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
entendo que por estar envolto em aspas o codigo esta ignorando o que vem depois da primeira virgula, enfim como transformar isso ['423,421,422'] em números separados para consulta!
ex: [423,421,422].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente você está recebendo como uma string `"423,421,422"`. Então seria necessário fazer um split nela pra poder separar os valores num array:

```
const array = id_mensagem.split(',')
```

Comment: show... deu boa!

Answer (score -1):

Na sua consulta, tente enviar a mensagem de resposta como um JSON, por exemplo:

```
res.send({id_mensagem: id_mensagem});
```

Que dessa forma ele enviará cada id_mensagem como um objeto e aí vc pode acessar o conteúdo de cada um pelo front assim:

```
response.data.id_mensagem
```

Acessando cada item separadamente e depois poder fazer o map.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: opa...obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Oi Rafael, creio que o AP está com problemas a enviar do front para o Node.js.